# Multiple variable regression by group not working - regression summary is repeating the same results

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a multiple regression per group, using the instructions in the following post: [How to apply OLS from statsmodels to groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088439/how-to-apply-ols-from-statsmodels-to-groupby).  My code snippet is as follows:

```
for coins in df_raw.symbol.unique():
    tempdf = df_raw[df_raw.symbol == coins]
    y = (df_raw['Lagged return']).astype(float)
    x1 = (df_raw['Excess daily return']).astype(float)
    x2 = (df_raw['Excess weekly return']).astype(float)
    x3 = (df_raw['Excess monthly return']).astype(float)
    x4 = (df_raw['Trading vol / mkt cap']).astype(float)
    x5 = (df_raw['Std dev']).astype(float)
    x6 = (df_raw['Residual risk']).astype(float)
    result = smf.ols(formula='y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6', data=df_raw).fit()
    print(result.params)
    print(result.summary())
```

However, when I run the regression I get exactly the same regression result repeating for every single group in the dataframe (despite the underlying data being different.)

```
Intercept    0.010033
x1          -0.000214
x2          -0.000014
x3          -0.000094
x4          -0.001902
x5          -0.000009
x6          -0.000006
```

Is anyone able to advise where I'm going wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `df_raw` with `tempdf`? Meaning `y = (df_raw['Lagged return']).astype(float)` should be `y = tempdf['Lagged return'].astype(float)` (same goes for x1, x2, x3...)

Comment: Thank you user3471881, your suggestion fixed the issue!  Appreciate your help :)....if you write this as an answer (rather than a comment) I will mark it as correct so you get the credit.  Thanks!